# Access Data Returned By SQL Select Query in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I'm very new to Ballerina. In my project i want to Access the data which is returned by a SQL select query?

what I'm trying to do is,

```
public function calculateCholesterol(int age,string gender,int totalCholesterol,int non_hd,int ldl,int hdl){

json data;

string sqlQuery;

sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM CHOLESTEROL WHERE gender = ? AND age = ?";

var result = cholesterolDB->select(sqlQuery,(),gender,selectedAge);

table<Cholesterol> cholTable = table{};

match result {

    table dataTable =>{
         //io:println(check <json>dataTable);
        var res = cholTable.add(dataTable);
        io:println(res);
    }

    error err =>{
        data  = {"Status":"Data Not Found","Error":err.message};
    }
}
}
```

But it is not working and throws a runtime error.

Comment: Can you post the thrown error as well?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved it today. I'm posting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
match result {

        table dataTable => {

            data = check <json>dataTable;
            correctData[0] = check <int>data[0].totalCholesterol;
            correctData[1] = check <int>data[0].non_hd;
            correctData[2] = check <int>data[0].hdl;
            correctData[3] = check <int>data[0].ldl;


        }

        error err => {
            data  = {"Status":"Data Not Found","Error":err.message};
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can do as follows.

```
table<Cholesterol> cholTable;

match result {

    table dataTable => cholTable = dataTable;

    error err => // handle error
}

// Now you can perform any required operation on the cholTable. 
// eg: You can iterate it, convert to JSON/XML. 

foreach row in cholTable {
   io:println("Info:" + row.totalCholesterol);
}
```

Please note that you cannot re-iterate a table returned from an SQL operation unless you set `loadToMemory` parameter in `select` operation. If you do as follows, then you can iterate is more than once.

eg:

```
var selectRet = testDB->select("SELECT * FROM student", Student, loadToMemory = true);
```

Please refer the [jdbc client](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/jdbc-client.html) example for more information.

Comment: Thank You. I will go through the above link.